# Will opened database connections still be opened after a "close-all"?

Tags: android

I found from other posts a way to `close` all `activities` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Logout.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); 

if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
    finish();
    return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
}
```

My question is : if there were opened `database connection` in some `activities` , will these opened connections be closed or not when the above code will execute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you've added this code to the activity:

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
    finish();
    return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
}
```

No, they won't be closed for you automatically. You should close connections at the `onDestroy` method, for example, to make this happen.

Comment: Ok , I have to override the `onDestroy` method in each activity and every connections will be automatically closed ?

Comment: @pheromix yes, if you close them explicitly in the overridden method